# What type of testing are we doing?

Tags: testing

Suppose we make a software. Once it is complete we test all of its functional requirements, if there is a bug we fix it, and if there is no bug in a requirement we check the next requirement until all requirements are tested.
What is this method of testing called?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "requirement-based testing", "testing against requirements" or simply "requirement testing". It basically just tests that the software meets each of its requirements.